# How to find entities with common parent using matching() in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I need to find all articles having the same author as a given list of articles

Here is my custom finder method:

```
public function findSimilar(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        if (empty($options['idList'])) {
            throw new Exception('idList is not populated');
        }
        // We are given a list of article IDs
        $idList = $options['idList'];

        return $query->matching('Authors', function ($q) use ($idList) {
            return $q->matching('Articles', function ($q2) use ($idList) {
                return $q2->where(['Articles.id IN' => $idList]);
            });
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error message:
PDOException: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Articles'`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few limitations with nested matching, and this may be one of them. I can't tell whether it maybe is a bug, so you may want to check the [**issues on GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) and eventually file a new one for clarification.

Quote from the docs:

> [...] Dotted matching paths should be used over nested matching() calls [...]

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

In either case, using dot notation instead of nesting should fix the problem, ie

```
return $query->matching('Authors.Articles', function ($q) use ($idList) {
    return $q->where(['Articles.id IN' => $idList]);
});
```

And if you'd wanted to also match on `Authors`, you could stack the matchers, like

```
return $query
    ->matching('Authors', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Authors.foo' => 'bar']);
    })
    ->matching('Authors.Articles', function ($q) use ($idList) {
        return $q->where(['Articles.id IN' => $idList]);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a HasMany relation we can do this easily with:

```
return $query->where([
   'Articles.author_id IN' => $this->find()
        ->select(['Articles.author_id'])
        ->where(['Articles.id IN' => $idList])
]);
```

// Thanks to jose_zap on the CakePHP IRC channel